# if multiple dice are thrown, how can I calculate their variance and mean?

Tags: probability, dice

from my calculation if 4 6-sided dice are thrown:

$$E[x] = 14.0 $$
$$E[x^2] = 207.66666.. $$
$$Var(x) = E[x^2]-(E[x])^2 = 11.666666666666657$$

would there be some general formula for a dice with each dice having n sides?

Comment: fair dice with $P(X=x)=\frac1n$?

Comment: surely it has to fair dice...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a fair die with $n$ sides, we get 
$$ E[x]=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n} i =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{1+n}{2}$$
And 
$$ E[x^2]=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n} i^2 =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n i^2=\frac{1}{6} 
(1+n) (1+2 n)$$

And of course 
$$Var[x]= \frac{1}{6} 
(1+n) (1+2 n)- (\frac{1+n}{2})^2  $$

By the way, since the dice are independent, $Var[X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4 ] = 4 Var[X_1]$ no matter how many sides the dice have. So you only need to calculate for one die and multiply.